# `image` in Matrix package not showing plot when in loop

Tags: r, image, for-loop, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a list of sparse matrices that I would like to make a series of images for. I want to be able to do this in a loop so that I can turn them into a GIF or mpg.

I can do this correctly for matrices generated using the `matrix()` command, but it doesn't work if I generate them using `sparseMatrix()`.
For example, this works:

```
    mList<-list()
    for (i in 1:4) {mList[[i]]<-matrix(runif(16),nrow=4,ncol=4)}
    for (i in 1:4) {image(mList[[i]])}
```

It results in adding 4 plots which I can view in the active plot window (by going back and forth through the history)
This does not work:

```
    mList<-list()
    for (i in 1:4) {mList[[i]]<-sparseMatrix(i=1:4,j=1:4,x=runif(4))}
    for (i in 1:4) {image(mList[[i]])}
```

Nothing happens. No images get created at all but no error messages show up to tell me why.
I can view each matrix image independently using e.g. `image(mList[[1]])` but it refuses to work from inside a for loop for some reason.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: The **SparseM** package appears to have an `image` method, but I don't see one in **Matrix** for sparse matrices. I could just be looking in the wrong place, though.

Comment: I think posting a question and then failing to give a upvote or a checkmark to a correct answer is terribly ungracious. Just because you failed to include all of your goals is no reason not to provide positive regard to an incremental step toward your (unstated, eventual) goal is shortsighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i in 1:4) { plot(image(mList[[i]])) }
```

does the trick.

```
lapply(mList, image)
```

also works.

The `Matrix:::image` function returns a `trellis` object (see the `lattice` package). The `print.trellis` function automatically plots any trellis object typed into the R console. That's why `image(mList[[i]])` works. However, in the for loop, the `print.trellis` function is never called and so the plot is never made. To actually show the plot you have to do `print(image(mList[[i]]))` or `plot(image(mList[[i]]))`.

For more information, see

```
?lattice
getMethod(Matrix:::image,"dgCMatrix")
getMethod(Matrix:::image,"dgTMatrix")
lattice:::print.trellis
lattice:::plot.trellis
```

Comment: This does indeed succeed in creating the images. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to feed the list into the animation builders, but at least its better than making them by hand.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. It works perfectly when I wrap with plot() and I am able to make GIF and HTML animations as well. Thank you very much!